# Exact bound on the number of simple paths in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations

What is the maximum number of simple paths between two vertices $s$ and $t$ in a graph $G=(V,E)$? I am looking for an upper bound for this problem.

**What I have done?** 
I assumed that $s$ and $t$ must be in a clique of size $n$. Let ${\cal P}_{st}$ be the set of all paths between $s$ and $t$, which we are interested in $|{\cal P}_{st}|$. Let ${\cal P}^{(k)}_{st}$ be the set of simple paths with length $k$ between $s$ and $t$ in $G$. Thus,

$$|{\cal P}_{st}| = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n-1}{|{\cal P}^{k)}_{st}|} =  \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n-1}{\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-1-k)!}} = T(n-2)$$

and I know that $T(n)=nT(n-1)+1$. Is there a way to calcualte the final results in terms of $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sum can be written as
$$(n-2)!\Bigl(1+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\cdots+\frac1{(n-2)!}\Bigr)\ ,$$
which is less than and very close to
$$(n-2)!\,e\ .$$

**Edit** in response to question.  The relative error is
$$\frac{e-{\displaystyle \Bigl(1+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\cdots+\frac1{(n-2)!}\Bigr)}}{{\displaystyle \Bigl(1+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\cdots+\frac1{(n-2)!}\Bigr)}}$$
which if $n$ is large is approximately
$$\frac1{(n-1)!\,e}\ .$$

Comment: Is there an exact value? How close is it exactly?

Comment: Well, you asked for an upper bound... but see edited answer.  The exact value is your sum.  There is no good exact simplification of the sum as far as I know.

Comment: @emab: We have $$T(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!}=n!e-\sum_{k\ge n+1}\frac{n!}{k!}\;,$$ and $$\sum_{k\ge n+1}\frac{n!}{k!}\le\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac1{(n+2)^k}=\frac1{(n+1)\left(1-\frac1{n+2}\right)}=\frac{n+2}{(n+1)^2}\;,$$ so $$0\le n!e-T(n)\le\frac{n+2}{(n+1)^2}\le\frac1n\;.$$ The absolute error in the approximation $T(n)\approx n!e$ is bounded by $\frac1n$, so the relative error is tiny for even moderately large $n$. And since $T(n)$ is an integer, we must have $T(n)=\lfloor n!e\rfloor$ exactly.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, this makes sense now.

Comment: @David I think you can add Brian's comment to the answer to get an exact value.

Comment: @emab: You’re welcome.